# Where can I find the icon files for "save" and "open" buttons on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, icons, nsworkspace

I am looking for icons in Cocoa for "save" and "open" buttons (floppy disk icon / opened folder icon) that are commonly used.

I searched the following path, as suggested: `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`

However, I couldn't find any default icons for "save" and "open" buttons.

Are there any default system icons for these two buttons?

Comment: Where are either of those even seen in a Cocoa app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the standard icons `kGenericFloppyIcon` and `kOpenFolderIcon`. You can obtain an `NSImage` for these using code like:

```
NSImage *folderIcon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kOpenFolderIcon)];
```

To see (most?) of the standard icons you can use Apple's [IconCollection sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I looked through IconCollection sample code, but didn't find a floppy disk icon (black floppy disk icon generally used for "save" button). Is it possible that it just does not exist?

Comment: It is `kGenericFloppyIcon`, however on recent OS X releases it shows an external floppy drive not a floppy disc. If you don't like that you could maybe use the hard disk image used for internal drives.